# Playing audio that is retrieved from url

Tags: iphone

I am getting a list of songs and its corresponding images from a url.The url is a json url. When i click the list a corresponding song is played. I have used AVFoundation Framework to play the song. Now the issue is that i need to play the next song after the playing of first song is completed. The corresponding images also must load. If i click the next or previous button the corresponding songs must be played. What is the best possible mechanism to attain it???

I have read about the Audio Queues and Audio Units but not sure how to use them. I'll be really helpful if i am provided with some sample code of how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing is to just place an `If` statement in `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` which is what is called after each sound is played (if playing them with an `AVAudioPlayer`).

You can also use that to update whatever images you need to as well based on the name.

Comment: Can u plz explain me with some sample code of how to do that coz i m a newbie to iphone dev...Plzzzz

Comment: This might get you pointed in the right direction: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/27285-play-sequence-audio-files-avaudioplayer.html